# Flutter: secret storages in phone

Tags: flutter

I have a encrypted file. I can decrypt this file. but when I decrpyt this file, I want to hide this file. Where can I hide this file. I try to hide cache. and I can put to cache. but file can be between 50MB to 150MB that is too much for cache. I need another way to hide. If you know a hiding place. Help please :)

this type is not solution. (.video.mp4)

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence "this type is not solution. (.video.mp4)"?

Comment: we can hide a file like .video.mp4. but I know that. I want, anyone can not reach that file in external Storage.

Comment: @FesaTR, do you find any solution regarding this issue? I have to implement same for audio file which only play inside from the app and not access out side of the app by user

Answer (score 0):

You can save the encrypted files in app's dedicated storage so the user (or any other app) has no access to it and you should handle opening the file in your app. For more information look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific).

```
      import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

      Future<void> saveEncryptedFile(File file) async {       
        final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
        final String path = '$dir/example.mp3';
        final File file = File(path);
        file.writeAsBytesSync(file);
      }
```

Comment: okey. so how can I watch this video when I want ? am I gonna code like this if I want to watch this video? "file.readAsBytesSync(file);"

Comment: You can read this tutorial to find out how to read and write files:  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files  @FesaTR